# Concatenating xargs with the use of if-else in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I've got two test files, namely, ttt.txt and ttt2.txt, the Content of which is shown as below:

```
 #ttt.txt
 (132) 123-2131
 543-732-3123
 238-3102-312


 #ttt2.txt
 1
 2
 3
```

I've already tried the following commands in bash and it works fine:

```
if grep -oE "(\(\d{3}\)[ ]?\d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})" ttt1.txt ; then echo "found"; fi
# with output 'found'

if grep -oE "(\(\d{3}\)[ ]?\d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})" ttt2.txt ; then echo "found"; fi
```

But when I combine the above command with xargs, it complains error '**-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'**'. Could anyone give me some explanation? Thanks in advance!

```
ll | awk '{print $9}' | grep ttt | xargs -I $  if grep --quiet -oE "(\(\d{3}\)[ ]?\d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})" $; then echo "found"; fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is a special character in bash (it marks variables) so don't use it as your `xargs` marker, you'll only get confused.

The real problem here though is that you are passing `if grep --quiet -oE "(\(\d{3}\)[ ]?\d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})" $` as the argument to xargs, and then the remainder of the line is being treated as a new command, because it breaks at the `;`.

You can wrap the whole thing in a sub-invocation of bash, so that xargs sees the whole command:

```
$ ll | awk '{print $9}' | grep ttt | xargs -I xx bash -c 'if grep --quiet -oE "(\(\d{3}\)[ ]?\d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})" xx; then echo "found"; fi'
found
```

Finally, `ll | awk '{print $9}' | grep ttt` is a needlessly complicated way of listing the files that you're looking for.  You actually you don't need any of the code above, just do this:

```
$ if grep --quiet -oE "(\(\d{3}\)[ ]?\d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})" ttt*; then echo "found"; fi
found
```

Alternatively, if you want to process each file in turn (which you don't need here, but you might want when this gets more complicated):

```
for file in ttt*
do
    if grep --quiet -oE "(\(\d{3}\)[ ]?\d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})" "$file"
    then
        echo "found"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks! that's very detailed and helpful :]